# next-i18next t(...).map is not a function

Tags: next.js, next-i18next

I just migrate my working app from react to nextjs.
I followed the tutorial provided by next and installed next-i18next but I'm not being able to map

I got this kind of object

```
 "skills": {
    "title": "Skills",
    "items": [
      {
        "title": "Javascript",
        "additionalInfo": [
          "React",
          "Node"
         ]
      }
    ]
}
```

and i need to parse the translation into this component

```
 {t("skills.items", { returnObjects: true }).map(
            ({ title, additionalInfo }, index) => (
              <Fragment key={index}>
                <TitleRow>
                  <p>{title}</p>
                </TitleRow>
    ...
```

Any ideas on what i missed in the migration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it may be t is not ready to be used in a first render...
If you're using the useTranslation hook, there should be a ready flag. => https://react.i18next.com/latest/usetranslation-hook#not-using-suspense
Or you can check for `!!t("skills.items", { returnObjects: true })` before calling map

Comment: This worked: i have to check 'ready', not !!